# Using 'isin' in python for three filters

Tags: python, numpy, nlp

I have the following dataframe

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list elements
data = ['george',
        'instagram',
        'nick',
        'basketball',
        'tennis']
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Unique Words'])
  
# print dataframe.
df
```

and I want to create a new column based on the following two lists that looks like this

```
key_words = ["football", "basketball", "tennis"]
usernames = ["instagram", "facebook", "snapchat"]

Label
-----
0
2
0
1
1
```

So the words that are in the list key_words take the label 1, in the list usernames take the label 2 and all the other the label 0.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a label map by numbering all of the elements in the first list as 1, and the other as 2.  Then you can use `.map` in pandas to map the values and fillna with 0.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list elements
data = ['george',
        'instagram',
        'nick',
        'basketball',
        'tennis']
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Unique Words'])
  
key_words = ["football", "basketball", "tennis"]
usernames = ["instagram", "facebook", "snapchat"]


label_map = {e: i+1 for i, l in enumerate([key_words,usernames]) for e in l}
print(label_map)

df['Label'] = df['Unique Words'].map(label_map).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Output

```
{'football': 1, 'basketball': 1, 'tennis': 1, 'instagram': 2, 'facebook': 2, 'snapchat': 2}

  Unique Words  Label
0       george      0
1    instagram      2
2         nick      0
3   basketball      1
4       tennis      1
```